# A difficulty in using squeeze theorem.

Tags: limits, functions, limits-without-lhopital

Given that: $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \sin^2(3x) \leq x^2f(x)\leq 3x^2 + 6\sin(x^2),$ then $$ \begin{equation*}
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}
f(x) =
\end{equation*}$$

i)0

ii)9

iii)$\infty$

iv) The limit does not exist.

My idea is to divide by $x^2$ the whole inequality and so the answer is 9, but I am hesitated to do this because I am not sure that $x^2 \ne 0$.

Comment: The limit literally means that x is approaching zero but isn't identically zero so you are fine, same thing happens in limits like $\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{x^2-1}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to 1} x+1 = 2$

Comment: @Triatticus you mean $x^2 - 1$ I think

Comment: Yes I did mean that, for some reason I wrote plus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limit $x\to 0$ tells you, how your function behaves when $x$ approaches $0$, but is not $0$, so your approach is correct.

For example, if

$h(x)=\begin{cases}
1& x\neq 0\\
2& x = 0
\end{cases}$

then $\lim_{x\to 0} h(x) = 1$, even though $h(0) = 2$.

Comment: So the correct answer is 9?

Comment: @Intuition I would say so:)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's the way to do it.  In a limit $x\to0$, you are assuming  $x\ne0$, so your idea works fine.

Comment: So the answer is 9 right?